# Forward all traffic when connected to a hub

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking, mirroring

I have a Ubuntu with two NICs. eth0 is connected to a hub and eth1 is connected to Internet. eth1 is used to do a point to point VPN using openVPN. So I have a tun0 interface. the VPN tunnel endpoints are 10.9.0.1 (binded on eth1) and 10.9.0.2 (remote peer). I want to forward/mirror all traffic received on eth0 (hub side) to the VPN peer 10.9.0.2. To do that, I created the following iptables rules.

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j TEE --gateway 10.9.0.2
```

And of course, I set eth0 in promiscuous mode.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 promisc
```

And I even activated ip forwarding

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'
```

When I sniff on eth0 (hub side), I see all traffic but when I sniff on 10.9.0.2 (remote VPN peer), I only see multicast traffic received on eth0. My question is: Why the non-multicast or dedicated unicast traffic is not mirrored/forwarded?

Note: If I sniff on tun0 on my Ubuntu server, I only see the multicast traffic and dedicated unicast traffic. So I conclude that the problem is not located on the iptables rules but before...

Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The idea given by @MrMajestyk has helped me. Here is my solution.

First, it is necessary to use **ebtables** to modify destination MAC address of the received packet in order that the IP stack's code receive the packet. If I don't do that at Ethernet layer, the network layer never receives the frames except multi-cast, broadcast and dedicated unicast. And if network layer never receives all the packets, it is not possible to handle them with **iptables**. But for this ebtables rule works, it is necessary to create a bridge interface with the incoming (hub side) interface on it.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 10.9.0.5
sudo brctl addbr br0 
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0 
sudo ifconfig br0 up
```

Then we can create the **ebtables** rules.

```
sudo ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -i eth0 -j redirect --redirect-target DROP
```

Then, I can use iptables to mirror my traffic received toward my VPN remote peer (10.9.0.2).

```
sudo iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j TEE --gateway 10.9.0.2
```

Please note that I use tunnel interface (tun) instead of ethernet bridge (tap). After that, I am able to sniff the on the remote peer 10.9.0.2 and I can see all traffic (except ARP for example).

I can even filter my traffic but it is necessary to do it inside the **raw table, prerouting chain** *before* the -j TEE --gateway rules. Look for example my iptables raw, prerouting entries.

```
-A PREROUTING -p vrrp -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p ospf -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p udp --sport 53 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --sport 53 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j TEE --gateway 10.9.0.2
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks for the name drop - don't I get points then ;-)

Comment: No problem @MrMajestyk ! See you !

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that forwarding of the kind you are doing does not work if the destination MAC is not actually on the machine you are using as a router. Broadcasts work by design. What you are looking for is probably more along the lines of mirroring a switch port. There is a thread on doing just that [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/how-to-route-forward-packets-in-promiscuous-mode-832698/). For sake of posterity, I'll repost the gist of it here:

```
                           SWITCH
                     +---------------+
                     |               |
SOURCE <------------>|<-----+------->|<------------> RCV
                     |      |        |
                     +---------------+
                            | Mirrored port ("tap")
                            | (output only)
                            |
                            |      +------------+
                            +<---->|   ROUTER   |<-------------> MONITOR
                             eth0  +------------+
```

> Here's how to rewrite the incoming MAC addresses to match eth0. eth0 has to be bound to a bridge device even if the bridge has no other devices. This allows ebtables to hook into it.

```
ifconfig eth0 X.X.X.X
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
ip link set br0 up (or ifconfig br0 up)
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -i eth0 -j redirect --redirect-target DROP
ip route add y.y.y.y dev eth0 (have to do for all expected incoming addresses/subnets)
```

Again - the above is just quoting the original post to make sure this can be brushed off at a later date too.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. I already seen this post. I understand that the use of ebtable to rewrite destination MAC but I don't really understand the command with route add. Why this command uses eth0 ? In my case, I want to forward the received data on eth0/br0 to another interface for example tun0.

Comment: Well as you figured out, it is mostly about making the bridge and then TEEing the traffic you want copied to the destination. I tried it but I couldn't make filtering work until I saw your note on the raw table. Good find - now that it works, I guess it makes perfect sense too :-)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to set iptables, just set the eth1's ip address as the gateway for eth0 and set the DNS in 'base' file, it would work.

Comment: No you haven't really understood the problem. I found the solution. Look my answer